# shopify does not supprt paypal website payment standard

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, shopify

I have a basic account with shopify and shopify is allowing me to choose from following paypal solutions

```
PayPal Website Payments Pro (UK)
PayPal Website Payments Pro (CA)
PayPal Payments Pro (US)
PayPal Payflow Link
PayPal Express Checkout
```

Is there a particular reason why shopify does not support "paypal website payment standard" ?

I am building an e-commerce solution for a client and am suggesting client to use "paypal website payment standard". Is this a not a favored solution for any reason?

Answer (score 1):

The integration options for PayPal standard aren't as robust as the other PayPal integrations so Shopify does not support it. Any of the options that standard provided should be covered by the other paypal products; you should be able to get the same functionality.

Is there something in particular from PayPal standard that the client needs that the other services don't provide?

Answer (score 0):

It is not about the functionality. It's about the monthly costs that is tied to other paypal plans. Paypal standard does not require any monthly fees. That's the difference and that is why we hope to actually use it on the website.